# How to ignore case in Vim's `:find` command?

Tags: vim

As title: How to ignore case in Vim's `:find` command?
Lots of information of ignore-case searching are about context searching.
But what I need is `:find` command case-insensitive.

Comment: `find` should support `regex`, where you can do any thing you can.

Comment: I know that, but I want to just ignore case anyway instead '[aA]xxx'.